# Fortran90 Array read blank values as null

Tags: arrays, fortran90

I'm reading data fram a external text file (30 Rows, 7 Columns), each row is seperated with a ",". I have missing values represented as ",,". When i read data into a two dimensional array the missing value is replaced with 0.00, but i have a 0.00 value in the data too. When i am computing average the count (number of items (n)) showd be count - (number of missing values). How can i pick the missing values dynamically.

Thanks
Sri

DATA

```
337.60,220.40,0.00,0.00,200.42,216.61,261.04
323.00,249.20,65.30,0.00,201.93,210.91,309.98
116.80,474.80,0.00,0.00,203.43,215.76,234.93
72.10,505.90,0.00,0.00,204.93,215.72,233.47
148.30,771.70,0.00,0.00,206.44,217.00,239.05
90.70,287.20,0.00,0.00,207.94,215.43,216.85
337.20,334.50,10.20,0.00,209.45,226.85,306.57
142.50,142.80,0.00,0.00,210.95,240.09,240.31
279.10,289.60,51.80,0.00,212.45,227.75,262.30
273.60,337.70,0.00,0.00,213.96,256.86,223.66
332.40,425.60,0.00,0.00,215.46,238.36,237.63
45.70,299.30,0.00,0.00,216.96,223.92,241.41
49.10,529.40,0.00,0.00,218.47,235.81,282.17
185.30,331.80,38.00,0.00,219.97,235.81,309.29
552.90,454.80,0.00,0.00,221.47,224.60,269.09
176.20,441.60,0.00,0.00,222.98,232.44,293.95
170.00,,0.00,,,,327.96
200.00,,0.00,,,,291.69
241.20,156.00,0.00,0.00,227.49,235.55,278.66
118.00,383.20,3.20,0.00,228.99,269.28,325.31
62.00,189.70,0.00,0.00,230.50,248.73,266.95
400.20,244.20,0.00,0.00,232.00,239.70,271.27
163.70,826.60,0.00,500.00,233.50,245.06,294.98
250.40,236.60,0.00,0.00,235.01,261.72,288.24
51.30,684.20,0.00,0.00,236.51,245.06,237.37
412.50,128.90,0.00,500.00,238.01,245.16,268.66
452.00,,,,,,314.68
481.00,155.50,0.00,0.00,241.02,278.72,348.44
162.20,201.90,0.00,500.00,242.52,250.36,255.58
171.80,152.00,0.00,500.00,244.03,246.85,339.06
```

Comment: gfortran accepts the string "nan" (without quotes) and translates them to floating point value NaN, which may be more interesting if negative values are permitted in your data (it also accepts "inf"). It's probably non standard though, and other compilers may have others means to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You do not seem to have negative values in your data, how about doing some pre-processing before passing the data to fortran, where you replace the ',,' with a negative value, for example with

```
sed 's/,,/,-1,/g'
```

Then you can easily identify these invalid data in your Fortran program and treat it accordingly.

Comment: NB, `sed` is *nix specific, so Windows users would have to use `find-replace` in their notepad/IDE (also a viable method for the *nix users who use an IDE instead of vi/nano).

Comment: Or a simple script in Awk, Python, Perl, Tcl... There are many solutions.